# openssh sftp chroot

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot

I chrooted a user to the directory `/var/www/upload` using `ChrootDirectory /var/www/upload` in my `etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

The permissions of all the files in `var/www/upload` is 755 and owner is root:upload_user.

However, I still cannot modify the files. (Getting a permission denied error.) 
Is it possible if I create a subdirectory with ownership `upload_user:upload_user`.

Is it, by any means, possible to allow my chrooted user to write to his / directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Is it possible if I create a subdirectory?

Yes, it will be possible to modify the files if you create a subdirectory.

### Is it, by any means, possible to allow my chrooted user to write to his home directory?

Using home directory for chrooting users is **highly discouraged** (but you asked "by any mean"):

Modify openssh source code and [introduce security breach](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/44657) :

> Is there another way to restrict SFTP to a user's home directory?
>   No, and I don't think one is necessary. If having to create a
>   subdirectory (which users can automatically be cd'd to on sftp login) is
>   so onerous then feel free to reintroduce CVE-2009-2904 by removing the
>   checks in session.c:safely_chroot().

Answer (score -2):

Change the directory mode to 770 or 775. With 755 only root has write acces to it. upload_user group only have read and execute/changedir.

Comment: 770 and 775 are likely to lead to "fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component" error messages.

Comment: If I do this I get a `fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www/upload"` error.